# What is the +0000 that is at the end of Unix/Posix timestamp?

Tags: posix, unix-timestamp

So, for example below is a timestamp generated by my Cassandra instance. What does the +0000 mean?

`2015-06-26 17:02:04+0000`

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the timezone offset. +0000 means UTC.

Comment: Specifically, the offset is in the form `[+-]HHMM` (hours & minutes without intervening colon).

Answer (score 0):

It's the ISO time format. Pretty common across many programming stuff.
[Here's the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)